# How to avoid exposing interfaces from other packages

Tags: java, maven, jar, interface, gradle

Let us say an Interface MyInterface is present in jar A. jar B implements the interface . Now if I have to use this interface I need to take a dependency on jar A and B . What is the best way to avoid this double dependency ? The problem is if you are using gradle you need to specify a version for jar A and jar B. Updating at 2 places is tricky and half of the times I see one of them is updated but not the other. One way I am thinking is implement MyInterface2 on jarB and ask to modify the downstream consumers to use MyInterface2 they can declare dependency only on Jar B. But gradle will do the transitive dependency walk so that they can declare only one version. Any thoughts/comments ?

```
//======> Jar A <======

public interface MyInterface {
  public void doSoemthing();
}

// ======> Jar B <=======

public class Impl1 implements MyInterface {
   public void doSomething() { }
}
```

The gradle file for Jar B will look something like

```
compile('package:jarA:<Version>')
```

======> Project 1 <============

```
MyInterface foo = new Impl1();
```

The gradle file will look something like

```
compile('package:jarA:<Version>')

compile('package:jarB:<Version>')
```

The problem I have is I want the gradle to pull in jarA from transitive dependency, but if it is not there I get an compilation error saying that it could not find MyInterface. But if I have the explicit version I need to update it at 2 places and need to track the version dependencies.

Is there an easier way ?

Comment: If B depends on A, and your project depends on B, you don't need to make it depend on A, since it's a transitive dependency. So you just need to set the version of B.

Comment: @JBNizet the consumer code does not want to take a dependency on one implementation and there are many implementations available for the interface. So it uses the MyInterface directly and this forces me to have the dependency. Am I missing something.

Comment: How does the consumer get an instance of the interface? Reflection? Because without reflection, it will have to create an instance of a concrete class, as in `List list = new ArrayList()`), and thus depend on B. Your proposed solution is to depend on B.jar, so why do you reject mine?

Comment: As @JB Nizet mentioned eventually the consumer will have to pick a concrete class to use so he will have to make his code dependent on the concrete class Jar (B, C, or anything else). Assuming that all concrete classes has a dependency on the interface jar adding a dependency on the concrete class jar would automatically download all dependent jars, including the one hosting the interface.

Comment: @JBNizet  I added an example to make it explicit. Please let me know if the question is still not clear

Comment: So, Project1 does have a dependency to B (because it needs Impl1 in the compile classpath), and B has a dependency to A (because it needs MyInterface in the compile classpath). It's thus redundant to add A to the dependencies of Project1: it's already there, transitively, by simply adding B to the dependencies.

Comment: @JBNizet I too thought so, but gradle is throwing compilation errors on the import statement of the interface as it is not defined in the B.

Comment: Then it means that the pom.xml file of B is incorrect: it should have A as a dependency and doesn't have it. Fix it.